NGinx Proxy_Pass config for subdomains and ports
Trying to setup different subdomains  *****.example.com to go to different ports (servers) on the local machine.  This is a windows box.
server {
listen 80;
server_name jellyfin.example.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8096;
}

}server {
listen 80;
server_name dynmap.example.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
}

}server {
listen 80;
server_name hfs.example.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1080;
}

}
This is kind of working, for the Jellyfin and the HFS, but the middle dynmap one gets stuck.  But works when going to example.com:8123  Or it works the first time or sometime.  Is there a better way to do this?

Has you checked NGINX error logs?
Verify that all virtualhost are running on their respective ports or try to adding health checks for your backend services, but maybe the intermittent issues with dynmap might be related to missing proxy headers (or WebSocket support if your application needs it).
for example:
# Common proxy headers that can be reused
proxy_headers {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jellyfin.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8096;
        include proxy_headers;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dynmap.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
        include proxy_headers;

        
        # in case of WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hfs.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1080;
        include proxy_headers;
    }
}

